# Is this thermolimiter faulty?

Tags: thermostat, oven

After recently replacing a broken fan element, my oven still doesn't heat up. I'm trying to establish whether the other elements are at fault or whether the faulty part is the thermolimiter.

The oven temperature light **comes on** (and never goes off). I have read in [multiple](https://www.espares.co.uk/advice/careandmaintenance/how-to-diagnose-problems-with-your-oven) [places](https://www.how-to-repair.com/help/fault-diagnosis-on-a-built-in-cooker-or-oven/) that this indicates a faulty element.

Testing the upper and lower heating elements I get about 55Ω, which I understand to be OK. But testing the part shown below I get no conductivity at all.

I think this part is the thermal cut-out. It's attached to the upper heating element.

[image]

Can anyone confirm based on my readings that this part is the faulty one, and also that the temperature light would be expected to be on regardless?

Comment: When taking ohm readings you must remove the wires first and then measure the element or thermolimiter alone, is that how you are making these readings?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. With the wires removed the thermolimiter  shows no conductivity between the connectors. Element readings give the same as when attached.

Comment: I've reworded my question, because I'm pretty sure this part is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the thermal cut-off doesn't test conductive, in this case near 0 Ohm, it is dead.

Get a replacement with the same temperature rating.

Comment: Thanks. It says T200, is that the temperature rating?

Comment: They tend to be labelled in Celsius. So T200 is likely 200C.